# Copy char* in C

Tags: c, pointers, char

Why does this function work?
I don't think that this is the proper way to copy a `char*` in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    const char* original = "TEST";
    char* copy;
    copy = original;

    printf("%s\n", original);
    printf("%x\n", &original);
    printf("%s\n", copy);
    printf("%x\n", &copy);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `copy = original;` is an error, due to discarding `const` qualifier without a cast. If you don't see error messages then please reconfigure your compiler so that the error message does appear.

Comment: Please take the [tour] and learn how to do research.  Particularly, check to see if others have asked similar questions: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%5Dcopy+string

Comment: Learn the language and specifically read about pointers, a char * is a pointer, you are not creating a copy, you are pointing to original which is also a pointer to the text "TEST".  original is a const pointer meaning you cannot reassign it.  copy can move.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not copy the string. You just assign the pointer `copy` with the address of the string literal which address is also stored in the  `original` pointer. Both point to the same place in the memory but have different types.

Comment: @PeterJ-01 Thanks dude.

Comment: This would be a better answer if it gave a clue how to actually copy the string.

Comment: It does not nessesary to be a string. His question is about the pointers and constants (char []literals in this case)

Answer (score 3):

No, you are not copying the string, you are accessing the same string through a
pointer.

If you want to copy a string, you have to use `strcpy`

> *man strcpy*
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strcpy(char *dest, const char *src);
> ```
>
> The  `strcpy()`  function  copies  the  string pointed to by `src`, including the terminating
>   null byte (`'\0'`), to the buffer pointed to by `dest`.  The strings may not overlap,
>   and the destination string dest must be large enough to receive the copy.
>   Beware of  buffer  overruns!

This copies a string.

```
const char *original = "TEST";
char copy[20];
strcpy(copy, original);
```

This is just variable assignment.

```
const char* original = "TEST";
char* copy;
copy = original;
```

`original` points to the start of the string `"TEST"`, which is a string literal
and thus points to read-only memory. That's why the type of the variable is
`const char*`. That tells you that you cannot modify the content pointed to by
the pointer. However, you may change the location to where it's pointing.

```
const char* original = "TEST";
original = "TEST1";  // OK
original[0] = 't';   // NOT OK
```

To the `printf`s:

```
printf("%s\n", original);
```

Prints the string pointed to by `original`

```
printf("%x\n", &original);
```

Prints the numerical address in hexadecimal format of the variable `original`.
Note that this is **not** where `original` points, but where `original` is
stored.

```
printf("%s\n", copy);
```

Sams as the first, different variable but pointing to the same location, hence
the result is the same.

```
printf("%x\n", &copy);
```

Same as the second one, but this time the address of the `copy` variable is
printed.

Note that if you want to print the address of a variable with `printf`, you
should use the `"%p"` conversion specifier.

Comment: `
char *src = "Hello";
char *dst = "World1";
strcpy(dst,src)
`
Is giving segmentation fault, why ?

Comment: @Zzz0_o because `dst` is pointing to read only memory, hence it crashes when you try to write in a read-only location. `char *src = "Hello"; char dst[] = "World"; strcpy(dst, src);` would work. However bare in mind, that `strcpy` is not a safe method, you should always use `strncpy` instead.

Comment: Also bear in mind that string literals are almost always const in nature. You should actually declare them as const, like this: `const char *str = "This is the correct way";`